# cannot get document id using box view api

Tags: box-api, box-view-api

In my app, after get "https://dl.boxcloud.com/*" url and send it to the View API, I receive this error:

```
{
message: "JSON parse error - No JSON object could be decoded"
type: "error"
request_id: "3ef12abcaf7a4c5abab5fb0d3959255e"
}
```

you can use this chrome extension to recreate this error

```
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo
```

I tried with the other rest clients and it work correctly. Except in my app and the extension above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried with the other rest clients and it work correctly. Except in my app and the extension above.

If this is the case, it's likely that the client you're using isn't actually sending properly formatted JSON. One way to debug this would be to output the raw HTTP request the client is sending and ensuring that it's actually sending the JSON properly.